# Stop webdriver when the mocha test times out

Tags: selenium, webdriver, mocha.js

I have a problem with running mocha and webdriverio. When the test times out the webdriver client continues to run anyways.

```
var assert = require('assert');                                                     
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');                                           

describe('suite', function() {                                                      

    beforeEach(function(callback) {                                                 
        this.client = webdriverio.remote().init(callback);                          
    });                                                                             

    it('test1', function(callback) {                                                
        this.timeout(500);                                                          
        this.client                                                                 
            .pause(550)                                                             
            .call(function() {                                                      
                assert(false, 'You shouldn\'t be here!');                           
            })                                                                      
            .call(callback);                                                        
    });                                                                             

    afterEach(function(callback) {                                                  
        this.client.end(callback);                                                  
    });                                                                             

});
```

When I execute `mocha test.js` I get:

```
  suite
    1) test1
    2) "after each" hook

  0 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1) suite test1:
     Error: timeout of 500ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:158:19)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

  2) suite "after each" hook:
     Uncaught AssertionError: You shouldn't be here!
      at WebdriverIO.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/test/test.js:15:17)
      at WebdriverIO.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/test/node_modules/webdriverio/lib/utils/PromiseHandler.js:146:26)
      at /Users/user/Documents/test/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/chainit/index.js:137:22
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I don't want or expect the second error to happen. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callbacks that Mocha provides for asynchronous functions can be called with an argument that contains the error that occurred. Catching the exception thrown by the assertion and passing it to `callback` allows Mocha to continue doing its work. Mocha just ignores the call to `callback`.

```
it('test1', function(callback) {
    this.timeout(500);
    this.client
        .pause(550)
        .call(function() {
            try {
                assert(false, 'You shouldn\'t be here!');
                callback();
            }
            catch (e) {
                callback(e);
            }
        });
});
```

The second `.call()` invocation has to be removed because in the case where the code does not timeout, then `callback` would be called twice.

If you want to avoid having to add the `try... catch...` everywhere you could use:

```
function handle_errors(test_code, callback) {
    return function () {
        try {
            test_code();
            callback();
        }
        catch (e) {
            callback(e);
        }
    };
}
```

And change the call to:

```
    this.client
        .pause(550)
        .call(handle_errors(function() {
            assert(false, 'You shouldn\'t be here!');
        }, callback));
```

Comment: Ok cool. I like this solution, seems legit, have no way to confirm it however because I don't have access to the project anymore but I will go ahead and mark it as correct as it's better than my answer :)

Comment: Glad to help! It is not impossible I missed something but I did test the code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own mocha wrapper that extended the regular mocha runner and was then able to catch the first error and stop the second one from being executed. Unfortunately there was no simple solution to this...